# name of this bouncing balls separator model

Tags: classical-mechanics

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRGf0Mq2Zwg

I want to read the physical and mathematical model of this "bouncing balls separator " in the above link .

What is name of this experiment so I can search it in literature ?

Comment: The model, which can be used to simulate this system, will not be very complicated. Namely collisions between spherical balls with a given coefficient of restitution. The macro behaviour of the system however is less obvious, so I assume you are referring to this?

Comment: Right I am referring to the macro behavior , modelling it and pulling the result that after certain time they all will accumulate in one partition only .